# When does XCode autocompletion suggest 'override' for Swift methods of a superclass?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When writing the code example below in XCode, while adding a method call to `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` the match shown by autocompletion doesn't include the `override` keyword.

However, the autocompletion suggestion when I'm adding `prepare(for segue:)` includes the `override` keyword.

Why is that?  I know that `override` implies that the method is part of the superclass, but I don't understand why XCode assumes one method can be overridden and the other can't.

```
import UIKit

class MusicListVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func loadThirdScreenPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let songTitle = "Quit Playing Games With My Heart"
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "PlaySongVC", sender: songTitle)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? PlaySongVC {
            if let song = sender as? String {
                destination.selectedSong = song
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are calling `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` you are calling the function that is already implemented by a class. When you define new function with the same name that superclass has you have to mark it with `override` so you do not define function with the same name by mistake.

Comment: With `dismiss`, you are *calling* a function defined in the superclass. For `prepare`, you are *redefining* its behavior.

Comment: GREAT assessment @NSDmitry, you should definitely help out on the review queues (see review link at the top), and increase your access/standing on the site.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is

- `dismiss` is a method **call** (in another method).
- `prepare(for` is a method **declaration** (on the top level of the class).

You can only override methods and properties when declaring them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **override** `prepare(for:sender:)` because you are implementing your own version of this method that you inherited from `UIViewController` (as you already stated). Xcode is able to infer this because you declared the type relationship when you wrote `MusicListVC: ViewController`. Thus it can provide you a helpful suggestion when and **where** you start typing. Xcode can infer that you are within the scope of a class and so again it can reasonably suggest that you declaring method or property.

For `dismiss(animated:completion:)`, you are calling an existing method that is defined by `UIViewController`. Because you are within the scope of another method (`backBtnPressed(_:)`) and of course based on what you start typing, Xcode can again infer that you want to **call** the `dismiss(animated:completion:)` method instead of overriding it.

If you change your scope, from within the `backBtnPressed(_:)` method to the scope of the class `MusicListVC`, then you will notice that when you start typing `dismiss(animated:completion:)` and hit enter, it will provide an **override** method template.

Xcode's assumptions are at the very least, based on **what** you are typing and **where** you are typing it.

Comment: I appreciate the info but still having a hard time understanding.  If someone could break down what this last block is actually doing line by line, it might help me understand    .override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? PlaySongVC {
            if let song = sender as? String {
                destination.selectedSong = song
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @TDG Apple provides a nice explanation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare (see the **discussion** section).

Comment: @TDG If that doesn't help, then I would suggest creating a separate question.